# MySQL bulk update slowing is too slow

Tags: php, mysql, database, query-optimization

Here I am only describing the essential fields for each table

### Table 1 :sysimport

(This master table is used to store list of imports)

1. InternalImportID (bigINT[20], PK )
2. ClientID(bigINT[20], fk for clients table which is not relevant here)

### Table 2 : sysImportDonationCS

(This is a temporary table used to store data before processing. After processing the rows are moved to tblDonation table. Some rows will remain in this table with status = "Discarded" and Notes = "Reason for discarding". At the beginning stage status is set as "NEW")

1. InternaltempID (bigINT[20], PK )
2. InternalImportID (bigINT[20], FK for sysimport )
3. Status (varchar(12))
4. Notes (mediumText)
5. GiftID (varchar(30))

### Table 3 : tblDonation

[This table is used to store data after processing]

1. InternalDonationID (bigINT[20], PK )
2. GiftNumber(varchar(255))
3. InternalImportID (bigINT[20], FK for sysimport )

I need a query

To update the rows in sysImportDonationCS table with status = "Discarded" and Notes = "Reason" and which matches sysImportDonationCS.GiftID and tblDonation.GiftNumber for the same client(same client is important point and connected via sysimport). I figured out a query which is working but now it is too time consuming.

Query

```
    UPDATE `sysimportdonationcs` as d INNER JOIN 
(SELECT donation.internalTempID as tID from sysimportdonationcs as donation 
INNER JOIN sysimport as s1 ON donation.`internalImportID` = s1.internalImportID INNER JOIN tbldonation ON donation.Gift_ID = tbldonation.giftNumber 
INNER JOIN sysimport as s2 ON  tbldonation.internalImportID = s2.internalImportID 
where s1.clientID = S2.clientID AND donation.status = 'NEW'  AND donation.internalImportID = $import_id order by tID limit 10) temp on temp.tID = d.internalTempID 
SET d.status = 'Discarded', d.notes = 'The job type was incremental and a matching record found in the tblDonation table.' ;
```

Some Status

- tblDonation Table contains 1,08,87,275 rows and which will grow
- sysImportDonationCS table contains 1.8 M rows
- I used limit in the above query to work as batch

I need to optimize the above query to work faster.

Comment: generic answer: JOIN+slow -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html et al is your friend... the friend you should ask first...

Comment: This query worked at first and after many attempts it suddenly stops and shows an error code with 1206. At the first stage i can update 10,000 records in a minute, but not a single row.

Comment: As a general rule, joining against a sub query will not use the index. So if your sub query brings back many rows then this will slow down dramatically. Can you use EXPLAIN (as suggested by @VolkerK ) on the sub query and post the results please?